# POST Method not working in <code> tag

Tags: php, html, post

```
<form name="submit_form" action="./uploads/submit.inc.php" method="POST">
        <div class="wrapper">
             <code id="ace-editorid" name="code_editor">Your Code Here</code>
        </div>  
        <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.1.3/ace.js'></script>
        <script  src="./css/script.js"></script>
        Type the Problem ID: <input type="text" name="probId">
        <input type="submit" name="b_code_submit" class="submit_query">
</form>
```

When user enters the code in the code editor and presses the submit_query button, then when i'm trying to extract the code in another php file using `$code = $_POST["code_editor"]` , then i'm getting nothing in the `$code` variable. But the code works fine when i use `<textarea>` tag instead of `<code>` tag.

Comment: Where is your input with name code_editor?

Comment: That's because a code tag doesn't work as an input element.

Comment: So how can i extract the code text from the <code> tag?

Comment: Read about form elements: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp

Comment: _"So how can i extract the code text from the <code> tag? "_ - that is the question your research should now focus on, correct. Doesn't mean you are supposed to outsource that research to us immediately though.

Comment: Just change the `<code>` elements to `<textarea>`.

Answer (score 0):

I personally will just change the code tag to a textarea tag. But if you must need to use a code tag, you will need to create another fake textarea that is hiding and duplicate the value from the code tag consistently when detected code tag is under modifying, because HTML page doesn't able to transfer code tag value to the server side without the aid of JavaScript (such as using JavaScript to get the code tag value first then use XMLHttpRequest to transfer it in the background, if you do this you are able to preserve your HTML page and dynamically update it without reloading the page). I will add "contenteditable" attribute to the code tag to make it editable. In addition, remember to edit your code tag first, otherwise, there will be no value transferred to the server side.

HTML code:

```
<form name="submit_form" action="./uploads/submit.inc.php" method="POST">
    <div class="wrapper">
         <code id="ace-editorid" name="code_editor" contenteditable>Your Code Here</code>
         <textarea id="new_textarea" name="new_textarea" style="display: none;"></textarea>
    </div>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("ace-editorid").oninput = function() {
            document.getElementById("new_textarea").innerText = document.getElementById("ace-editorid").innerHTML;
        //update fake textarea every time there is a change in the code tag.
        }
    </script>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.1.3/ace.js'></script>
    <script  src="./css/script.js"></script>
    Type the Problem ID: <input type="text" name="probId">
    <input type="submit" name="b_code_submit" class="submit_query">
</form>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
    echo "Code tag value: <br>".$_POST["new_textarea"]."<br>";
    echo "Problem ID: ".$_POST["probId"];
?>
```

Comment: I guess you intend to create a online program testing system. I had done that almost 2 years ago.